# Writing in pointfree style f x = g x x

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I am learning Haskell. I'm sorry for asking a very basic question but I cant seem to find the answer. I have a function f defined by :

```
f x = g x x
```

where g is an already defined function of 2 arguments. How do I write this pointfree style?
Edit : without using a lambda expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`f` can be written with [`Control.Monad.join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3ajoin):

```
f = join g
```

`join` on the function monad is one of the primitives used when constructing point-free expressions<s>, as it cannot be defined in a point-free style itself (its [SKI calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) equivalent, `SII` — `ap id id` in Haskell — doesn't type)</s>.

Comment: I think you mean `f = join g`

Comment: Can you explain why my answer would not be `point free`? I guess I have a misunderstanding.

Comment: @pmr: Point-free means the elimination of named parameters; `x` is a point in your definition.

Comment: @pmr, writing in point-free style means that you omit the introduction of explicit variables. While you have made `f` "explicit-argument-less," you still introduce the explicit variable `x` later on in the definition, making the definition pointful.

Comment: This SKI thing is very interesting. Indeed SII is what I need. I don't understand what you mean by "ap id id" and "doesn't type". Also I don't know what join is but I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: @user1188374, the `join` function is a fundamental function for monads, the monad in this case being the function monad, `(->) r` for some `r`. The definition of `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`; substituting `(->) r` for `m` yields `join :: (r -> r -> a) -> (r -> a)`.

Comment: @user1188374: `join` is a primitive of point-free style because the translation of `SII` to Haskell, `ap id id`, isn't valid — it has a type error (specifically, it fails the [occurs check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check)). It works in the SKI combinator calculus because it's untyped.

Comment: @dflemstr Thanks. I was under the wrong impression that it only meant not to have any variables on the left hand side.

Comment: `join` is equal to `flip ap id`, so it could be argued that it is not a primitive.

Be aware that while some SKI expressions don't type, they are not usually unique, and sometimes an alternative will do better. For example, `I = SKK = SKS`, but of those two only `ap const const` has the type that you want.

Comment: @dflemstr: Where is the function monad instance actually defined in Haskell / libraries?  In `ghci`, `Control.Monad.join (+)` gives an error: ` No instance for (Monad ((->) a0))  arising from a use of `join'    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) a0))`. (I see that Control.Monad haddock has `instance Monad ((->) r)`, but there is no corresponding source (because it's primitive in GHC?) and there's a step missing for me.)

Comment: @misterbee it is declared in [Control.Monad.Instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html).

Comment: @dflemstr: Ah, thanks. I guess that was obvious in retrospect, but it's hard to search for `->`,  and of course [`-- This module deliberately declares orphan instances:`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html), which also hinders discoverability....

Comment: @ehird: `join` cannot be considered as a primitive, because it can be implemented in terms of `<*>` and `pure` (`S` and `K`, respectively). `SII` is equivalent to `λx.xx` while `join` is `λfx.fxx`. The former cannot be typed no matter what expression you use. You could define `join = S(S(KS)(S(S(KS)K)(KI)))(KI)`.

Comment: Or, well, also `join = SS(KI)`.

Answer (score 9):

This is known as ["W" combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Instances
import Control.Applicative

f = join g       -- = Wg        (also, join = (id =<<))
  = (g `ap` id)  -- \x -> g x (id x) = SgI
  = (<*> id) g   --                  = CSIg
  = g =<< id     -- \x -> g (id x) x
  = id =<< g     -- \x -> id (g x) x
```

[**S,K,I**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) are one basic set of combinators; [**B,C,K,W**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system) are another - you've got to stop *somewhere* <sup>(re: your "no lambda expression" comment)</sup>:

```
_B = (.)     -- _B f g x = f (g x)     = S(KS)K
_C = flip    -- _C f x y = f y x       = S(S(K(S(KS)K))S)(KK)
_K = const   -- _K x y   = x
_W = join    -- _W f x   = f x x       = CSI = SS(KI) = SS(SK)
_S = ap      -- _S f g x = f x (g x)   = B(B(BW)C)(BB) = B(BW)(BBC)
   = (<*>)                                -- from Control.Applicative
_I = id      -- _I x     = x           = WK = SKK = SKS = SK(...)

{-
Wgx = gxx 
    = SgIx = CSIgx 
           = Sg(KIg)x = SS(KI)gx
    = gx(Kx(gx)) = gx(SKgx) = Sg(SKg)x = SS(SK)gx

-- _W (,) 5 = (5,5)
-- _S _I _I x = x x = _omega x         -- self-application, untypeable
-}
```

Comment: The stopping point is one combinator. One example is the `ι` (iota) combinator - `λf.fSK`, `SKI` is then expressed as `S = ι(ι(ι(ιι)))`, `K = ι(ι(ιι))` and `I = ιι`. This base is not so friendly for simply typed λ-calculus, `ιι` doesn't even typecheck. `U = λf.fKSK` is a bit better (I don't know if it has a name, so I'm just calling it `U` as universal); `S = U(UU)` and `K = UUU`

Comment: @Vitus [yes, yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#One-point_basis). It's more a question of convenience I guess, *where* to stop, in a *practical* setting. In Haskell for instance, it's convenient that we have SKI *and* BCKW combinators.

Comment: ... also, `f = g =<< id = id =<< g`.

Answer (score 1):

I got here by pure chance, and I want to offer my solution, as nobody has mentioned lifting yet in this thread, not explicitly at least.

This is a solution:

```
f = liftM2 g id id
```

How to look at it?

- `g` has type `a -> a -> b`, i.e. it takes *two values of some type* (the same type for both, otherwise the definition the OP gave of `f` wouldn't make sense), and gives back another *value of some type* (not necessarily of the same type as the arguments);
- `lift2M g` is the lifted version of `g` and it has type `(Monad m) => m a -> m a -> m b`: it takes *two monadic values*, which are each a value in a so-far-unspecified context, and gives back a *monadic value*;
- when passing two functions to `liftM2 g`, the die is cast on what the context of the `Monad` is: it is that the values are not in there yet, but will eventually be, when the function will receive the arguments it needs; in other words, functions are monads that store their own future values; therefore, `lift2M g` takes in input two functions (or, *the future values* of two functions), and gives back the another function (or, its *future value*); knowing this, its type is the same as above if you change `m` to `(->) r`, or `r ->`: `(r -> a) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`
- the two functions that we pass are both `id`, which promises it'll give back the same value it receives;
- `liftM2 g id id` is therefore a function of type `r -> b` that passes its argument to those two `id`s, which let it unchanged and forward it to `g`.

In a similar fashion, one can exploit that functions are applicative functors, and use this solution:

```
f = g <$> id <*> id
```

Comment: or `liftA2`, the same as `liftM2` for functions (i.e. Reader monad): `liftA2 k f g x = k (f x) (g x)`. (this just in: `liftA2 (,) === (&&&)` :) ).

Comment: Hi @WillNess, every comment of yours adds one empty checkbox on my to-learn list, ahahah. This language just makes me wanna come back to uni. Well, I wouldn't even know where I can study it in Italy :/. I guess I'd have to search.

Comment: search for Eugenio Moggi, for starters. :)  (BTW, `g <$> x <*> y` === `liftA2 g x y`, more or less by definition IIRC)