# Haskell: Inverting 'map'

Tags: haskell

As you may already know when you use map it takes a function and applies that function to every element of a list

```
map f xs is the list obtained by applying f to each element of xs, i.e.,
```

But in my case I have a list of functions that need to be applied in order to an specific value. These are the types, to give a better idea:

```
data Auto = Auto {plate :: String, currentTank :: Int, tanqSize :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq)
type Services = Car -> Car
service :: Car -> [Services] -> Car
```

As I explained before [Services] will be a list of functions that take in `Car` and return `Car`. I need to apply in order those functions to the `Car` that takes `service` and return it with all the modifications done.

Here are some examples of functions that may appear on the list:

```
emptyTank :: Services
reFuel :: Int -> Services
changePlate :: String -> Services
upgradeTank :: Int -> Services
```

Does anyone know a way to solve this? In case you know a more appropriate function to use instead of map, tell me and I'll look into it.

Comment: Lookup `$`, `flip`, and currying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: mapping function application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134857/haskell-mapping-function-application)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the suggestion; `service` needs to return a single `Car`, not a list of type `[Car]`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" along with "[mre]" and their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foldl` for this:

```
service :: Car -> [Services] -> Car
service car functions = foldl (flip ($)) car functions

service someCar [emptyTank, (refuel 10), (changePlate "abc 123"), (upgradeTank 15)]
```

`($)` is function application, but to use it with `foldl` (to apply the functions in the correct order, we need to flip its arguments so that `arg $ f` evaluates to `f arg`. Using `(flip ($))` with `foldl` will cause the first function in `functions` to be applied to `car`, then the second function will be applied to the result of the first, then the third to the result of the second, etc.

(`foldr` could be used with simply `($)` instead of `flip ($)`, but it would apply the functions from right to left, not left to right. Compare

```
foldl (flip ($)) 3 [(+4), (*5)]  -- Returns (3+4)*5 = 35
```

with

```
foldr ($) 3 [(+4), (*5)] -- Returns (3*5) + 4 = 19
```

)

---

Another way of looking at this is that you want to compose your list of functions into one function:

```
(upgradeTank 15) . (changePlate "abc 123") . (refuel 10) . emptyTank $ someCar
```

which you can also do with `foldl` (or `foldr`? It doesn't seem to make a difference which you use here), using `(.)` to reduce the list to a single function, then applying that function to `car`. The `id` function is used as the other argument for the first call to `(.)` made by `foldl`. You do need to reverse the list of functions first, though, since composition is right-associative.

```
service car functions = foldl (.) id (reverse functions) $ car
```

Comment: Thanks, here is how i used what you told me:                                       Services (Car plate currentTanq tanqSize) list = foldl (flip ($)) (Car plate currentTanq tanqSize) list

Answer (score 0):

The fold answer is pretty accurate and I think is the best, but I have found an alternative which isn't too much slower only 0.003% less scalability.
Using pattern matching and recursion.

```
apply_all x [] = x
apply_all x function_list = apply_all ((head function_list) x) (tail function_list)
```