# Haskell - How to write (.) f f = (\x -> f (f x))

Tags: haskell, math, ghci, calculus

I need to write on a module to be run on GHCi, with a function composition to the same function. This (The classic `fog(x) = f(g(x))`) runs:

```
(.) f g = (\x -> f (g x)).
```

The problem appears when I try to write it like this

```
(.) f f = (\x -> f (f x)).   (fof(x) = f(f(x)))
```

GHCi says:

```
"Conflicting definitions for `f'
 Bound at: Lab1.hs:27:9
           Lab1.hs:27:12"
```

Line 27:9 appear on the first time f and line 27:12 appear f again.

Why doesn't Haskell understand `(.) f f = (\x -> f (f x))`?

Comment: Are you trying to pattern match for the case that both arguments are equal? Because in that case you don't just have a syntactical problem (need to use different names for different arguments) but also a conceptual problem (equality for functions is - in general - undecidable).

Comment: Do you want `twice f = \x -> f (f x)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, arguments to a function must have unique names. Using the same name for another argument is not allowed. This is because

```
foo x y = ...    ===    foo = (\x-> (\y-> ...))
```

and if `y` where replaced with `x`, the second `x` would just shadow the first inside the `...` body: there would be no way to reference the first `x` from there.

You can just define `twice f x = f (f x)`:

> Prelude> :t twice 
>   twice :: (t -> t) -> t -> t 
>   Prelude> twice (+1) 4 
>   6

---

Alternatively, `f (f x) = (.) f f x = join (.) f x`:

> Prelude Control.Monad> :t join (.) 
>   join (.) :: (b -> b) -> b -> b

`join` is defined in `Control.Monad`. For functions, it holds that `join g x = g x x`. It is also known as [**W** combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050971/849891).

E.g. `print $ join (.) (+1) 4` [prints 6](http://ideone.com/xuxLGk).

Answer (score 7):

As the error message says, you have conflicting definitions for `f` in the definition `(.) f f = (\x -> f (f x))`. You are binding the name `f` to both the first and second arguments to `(.)`, so `ghci` doesn't know which argument to use when evaluating the expression `f x`.

There is nothing wrong with defining `(.)` using the pattern `(.) f g`, and then calling it with two arguments that happen to be the same.

Comment: But i need to write like (.) f f , I know that (.) f g is correctly write cose i run and probe on GHCI. I think it has to be a form to write (.) f f correctly, to me its a syntacs problem.

Comment: user3421938: nope, you can't do it:

λ let doesThisWork nope nope = nope

<interactive>:44:18:
    Conflicting definitions for ‘nope’
    Bound at: <interactive>:44:18-21
              <interactive>:44:23-26
    In an equation for ‘doesThisWork’